# SFDX And scratch org configuration

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

I am a little confused on how to properly use scartch orgs. Lets say I have apex + visualforce page that I need to edit, and that visualforce page interacts with many custom objects/custom fields and other dependencies. Do I really have to remember everything that visualforce page/apex touches and bring it over to the scratch org? Seems very easy to make a mistake when you deploy to production and functionality isn't what you expected due to you missing processes and dependencies in the scratch org vs production.

Answer (score 3):

SFDX doesn't envision editing a single piece of metadata plus its dependencies in a scratch org. Rather, the SFDX model recommends breaking your overall org into a number of independent packages. This is called the [Package Development Model](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/sfdx_dev_model) (link is to the Trailhead module of the same name).

A package, in this parlance, includes all of the metadata (including dependencies) that falls within some logical unit. That might include a group of custom objects for some functional area in your org, their page layouts, and all of the automation related to those objects, while a separate package could include the same types of metadata for a different functional area of your org.

A scratch org would typically contain the metadata for one package, which is developed as a unit. You wouldn't populate a scratch org with a single metadata item even if it were feasible, and it's generally not due to the high interconnectivity of Salesforce metadata.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to "remember" anything<sup>1</sup>. All you need to do is create a new Package (Setup > Packaging > Package Manager). Add your Visualforce page to the package, and Salesforce will recursively add all your dependencies. You can then retrieve this using `force:source:retrieve -n "My Package"`, and it will get basically all the required<sup>2</sup> metadata. From there, you can typically just `force:source:push` to your scratch org, and you're ready to go.

---

<sup>1</sup> This statement presumes that you don't use dynamic Apex (e.g. dynamic SOQL). If you do, you'll want to document and remember those loose dependencies. This is typically rare in most orgs.

<sup>2</sup> You may still need to figure out which org settings may apply, etc, but this will be approximately 90-95% of all the metadata you need.

Comment: @sfdxfox i think we will also need to convert it before pushing or if you need to work on it locally

Comment: @AnshulAgrawal `force:source:retrieve` retrieves in DX format, not MDAPI format. As such, no conversion is typically necessary for pushing or creating Unlocked Packages. Also, no need to convert to work on locally in updated IDEs.